# StableSwap invariant and price computation

Tags: blockchain, uniswap, price, stablecoins

Having issue reproducing the price Curve.fi propose for swaping tokens.

Let's take [tricrypto2](https://curve.fi/tricrypto2) pool for example.

As I'm writing this, the actual balance of the pool is the following:
[image: tricrypto2 as of 2022-05-19, 5pm]

I'm trying to re-compute the **wBTC/USDT** exchange rate, for a swap of **100 wBTC**: **1 wBTC = 29,488.3382 USDT** as seen on the screen.

The original [StableSwap paper](https://curve.fi/files/stableswap-paper.pdf) gives this formula of the invariant:

[image: StableSwap invariant]

Here we thus have the following:

- A = **85** (according to the paper)
- n = **3**
- Sum of x_i = **152,114,067.26000002**
- Product of x_i = **58,864,002,783,941,336 = 5.8864003e+16** (number is indeed bigger than a double can contain but it should be ok for atleast a good approximation).

The point is to find **D** s.t. this equation is always true.

For that I used Newton algorithm, and it gives me **D = 26,041,385.157773785** (precision of approx 1e-5, can't seem to be able to converge really well for unbalanced pools, but this should still do).

After that, I want to compute the quantity of **USDT** the pool will give me for **100 wBTC**:

- Quantity of added **wBTC = 100 * (1 - 0.00059) = 99.941** (0.059% being the fee)
- New quantity of **wBTC** in the pool = **5,074.33+ 99.941 = 5,174.271**

And now I want to compute the quantity of **USDT** that I will receive. So I also use Newton algorithm to solve StableSwap equation with the value of **D** computed above (26,041,385.157773785), and the new quantity of **wBTC** (5,174.2709999999997), the quantity of **ETH** being of course unchanged throughout the all process (76,301.68).
It gives me:

- New quantity of **USDT = 150,694,937.54155532**

Which gives me a received quantity of:

- Quantity of USDT received: **initial - new = 152,032,691.25 - 150,694,937.54155532 = 1,337,753.7084446847**

And so an exchange rate of: **1 wBTC = 13,377.537084446847 USDT**, which is obvisouly wrong...

The thing is, I really don't see what I'm doing wrong. Maths here are trivial but I can't manage to find where the error in my code is, or what I missed.

This is my C++ code (you can run it here: https://onlinegdb.com/ULNb-9qDG):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, double> map = {
        {"USDT", 152032691.25},
        {"wBTC", 5074.33},
        {"WETH", 76301.68}
    };
    
    std::string ref = "wBTC";
    std::string tgt = "USDT";
    
    double quantity = 100;
    double fee = 0.00059;
    const double amount_in_fees = quantity * (1.0 - fee);
    
    double a = 85;
    double n = map.size();
    double nn = std::pow(n, n);
    
    double s = 0.0 /* initial sum invariant */, p = 1.0 /* initial product invariant */;
    std::for_each(map.begin(), map.end(), [&](std::pair<std::string, double> pair) { s += pair.second; });
    std::for_each(map.begin(), map.end(), [&](std::pair<std::string, double> pair) { p *= pair.second; });
    
    auto&& invariant = [&](const double d) -> double
    {
        return (std::pow(d, n + 1) / (nn * p)) + (a * d * nn) - d - (a * nn * s);
    };
    
    double d = 26041385.157773785; // This is "D" right here
    double test_invariant = invariant(d); // = 6.103515625e-05 so not bad
    
    const double nq1 = map.at(ref) + amount_in_fees;
    double s_bis = nq1, p_bis = nq1;
    std::for_each(map.begin(), map.end(), [&](std::pair<std::string, double> pair) { if (pair.first != ref && pair.first != tgt) { s_bis += pair.second; } });
    std::for_each(map.begin(), map.end(), [&](std::pair<std::string, double> pair) { if (pair.first != ref && pair.first != tgt) { p_bis *= pair.second; } });
    
    auto&& invariant_with_new_tgt = [&](const double nq2) -> double
    {
        return a * d * nn + std::pow(d, n + 1) / (nn * (p_bis * nq2)) - d - a * nn * (s_bis + nq2);
    };
    
    double nq2 = 150694937.54155532; // New quantity of USDT
    double test_invariant_with_new_tgt = invariant_with_new_tgt(nq2); // = -6.103515625e-05 so not bad too
    
    const double received = map.at(tgt) - nq2;
    double price = received / quantity;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without digging into this I would assume that your amplification coefficient is incorrect if you took it from the docs. To get the current coefficient of the pool you should check the actual contract implementation for that pool here.

`https://etherscan.io/address/0xd51a44d3fae010294c616388b506acda1bfaae46#readContract`

You can call the view function `A` which will return the parameter.

If you're still not getting the correct results you should check the implementation of the `exchange` call in the code. Seems like they also use Newton to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that you are using the stableswap equation for a pool that is not a stableswap (coins are not pegged).  The tricrypto2 pool is instead based on the cryptoswap invariant.  See the [whitepaper](https://classic.curve.fi/files/crypto-pools-paper.pdf).